Get location on tap mapkit ios 18
In my app I use a MapReader and onTapGesture to get the coordinates of user tap in order to create markers or detect a click on a MKPolygon.
//
//  CreatingBuildingView.swift
//  Project_m
//
//  Created by Arthur Junges on 08/05/2024.
//

import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct CreatingBuildingView: View {
    @Namespace private var mapScope
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(AppState.self) var appState
    
    @State private var locationPermission: LocationPermission = .init()
    @State private var isAlertManualPermPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var drawBuildingsMarkers: [DrawPoint] = []
    @State private var isLoading: Bool = false
    @State private var showingBuildingNameDialog: Bool = false
    @State private var buildingName: String = ""
    @State private var buildingCreationError: Error?
    
    @Binding var buildings: [Building]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                MapReader { mapProxy in
                    ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                        Map(scope: mapScope) {
                            
                            ForEach(drawBuildingsMarkers) { marker in
                                Marker(marker.title, coordinate: marker.point)
                            }
                            
                            if drawBuildingsMarkers.count > 2 {
                                MapPolygon(coordinates: drawBuildingsMarkers.map { elem in elem.point})
                                    .foregroundStyle(Color(.red).opacity(0.5))
                                    .stroke(Color(.red), lineWidth: 2)
                            }
                        }
                        .onTapGesture { screenCoord in
                            print("inside")
                            let markerData = mapProxy.markerData(screenCoordinate: screenCoord, geometryProxy: geometryProxy, pointsCount: drawBuildingsMarkers.count)
                            
                            if let md = markerData{
                                drawBuildingsMarkers.append(md)
                            }
                        }
                        .mapControls {
                            MapScaleView()
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            if locationPermission.authorizationStatus == .denied || locationPermission.authorizationStatus == .restricted {
                                isAlertManualPermPresented = true
                            }
                            locationPermission.requestLocationPermission()
                        }
                        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                            Text("Tap on the map to draw the bounds")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .padding(8)
                                .font(.system(size: 13))
                                .opacity(0.6)
                                .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        }
                        .alert("Allow localization", isPresented: $isAlertManualPermPresented) {
                            Button("Cancel") {
                                isAlertManualPermPresented = false
                            }
                            Button("Settings") {
                                if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
                                    // Ask the system to open that URL.
                                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        message: {
                            Text("Localization authorization was previously declined. Please click settings and allow localization")
                        }
                        // This is needed in order to make the controls "on top" on the map to allow user to click on them
                        // Otherwise, the tap event would be handled by "onTapGesture"
                        VStack() {
                            MapCompass(scope: mapScope)
                            MapUserLocationButton(scope: mapScope)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .padding([.bottom], 16)
                        .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle)
                    }
                    .mapScope(mapScope)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Sadly it seems that in ios 18 onTapGesture is dreprecated. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapselectablecontentview/4293059-ontapgesture
How to convert tap gesture to coordinate in a SwiftUI Map view? This was a similar issue in the past on how to get coordinates. But I believe it is no longer viable.
As of now the only solutions I can see are:

Maybe someone can hint me at a native SwiftUi / mapkit solution
Or I will replace mapkit with MapBox


It's weird that the call would resolve to the deprecated overload. How about .onTapGesture(coordinateSpace: LocalCoordinateSpace.local) { screenCoord in ... }?

Indeed in did not make sense, it looks like my timing was unlucky, I was in between betas and changing APIS. It's all good on beta 3. Thank you so much for you help, you really helped me figure this out.

The solution was simply updating to ios 18 beta 3. The onTapGesture was deprecated in beta 1 or 2, and only brought back with a different signature in beta 3.
